# Command prompt closing too quickly

Tags: python, command-prompt, pyinstaller

I know there are lots of questions on this topic, however none so far is the result of a pyinstaller package.

I used pyinstaller to package a python file. It runs well before packaging, but when I open the exe, it briefly displays an error and closes before I get the chance to read.

How can I stop the command prompt from doing so, or how else can I view this log?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Manually open a command prompt (**Start > Run > cmd**), navigate to the folder containing your program (`cd C:/Users/Ladmerc/python_programs`), and then run the program (`my_program.exe`). The terminal window will stay open after the program exits.

Comment: Thanks! worked for me. The error is from pyinstaller not loading scipy

Answer (score 4):

You can always open the command line and then run the executable from there. I'm sure there are other ways, but this is the first that I thought of. Here's a [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/209694/running-an-.exe-file-via-command-prompt/) that may be helpful.